# Retreving date from Hibernate TImestamp

Tags: java, hibernate, timestamp

I have a field with temporal type as Timestamp to save both date and time to the database.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="date", nullable=false)
private Date date;
```

But when displaying the value to the user, I just want to show date part and truncate time part. I tried this but I get ParseException probably because of the Nanosecond part of the Hibernate Timestamp.

```
 SimplDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
 return sd.parse(date.toString());
```

So how do I retrieve just date from Hibernate Timestamp? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just format the date object. The `toString` method isn't guaranteed to give you a string in a format that can then be parsed.

```
String dateStr = sd.format(date);
```

That will give you a date string in MM/dd/yyyy format that you can then convert back into a Date.

```
Date fancyNancy = sd.parse(dateStr);
```

---

*** EDIT ***

Run this code and verify it prints out the day, month and year with no time.

```
try {
    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    System.out.println("Original Date: " + d);
    System.out.println("Formatted Date: " + df.parse(df.format(d)));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. that didn't give me what I wanted `SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); return sd.parse(sd.format(created));` resulted in **Fri Sep 02 11:12:34 EDT 2011**

Comment: You shouldn't be getting a time component, but yes when you print out a date it is going to display in that format. Are you trying to get the date component or its string representation?

Comment: The javadocs explain how to specify the format string for any combination of date and time using date and time patterns (with examples).         http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html